# Manipulating the Boltzmann equation for baryons

Tags: statistical-mechanics, cosmology, perturbation-theory, differential-equations

The Boltzmann equation for baryons is
$$m_p\frac{\partial (n_b u_b^j)}{\partial t} + 4Hm_pn_bu_b^j + \frac{m_pn_b}{a} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x^j} = F_{e\gamma}^j(\vec{x},t)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ eqn.(1)$$

where $m_p$ is the mass of the proton, $n_b$ is the number density of baryons, $u_b^j$ is the bulk velocity of baryons (considered a first order perturbation), $\Psi$ is a first order perturbation to the metric and $F_{e\gamma}^j$ is the collision term for Compton scattering.

The above equation has to be divided by $\rho_b = m_p\overline{n_b}$, where $n_b(x, t)= \overline{n_b}(t)[1 +δ_c(x, t)]$ and $\delta_c$ is the over-density perturbation. Working to first order in perturbations, equation (1) becomes

$$\frac{\partial u_b^j}{\partial t} + Hu_b^j + \frac{1}{a} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x^j} = \frac{1}{\rho_b}F_{e\gamma}^j(\vec{x},t)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ eqn.(2)$$

I have two questions. It seems like $\overline{n_b}$ from the first term in equation (1) has come outside the partial derivative with respect to time. But $\overline{n_b}$ is a function of time.

The second question is related to how the factor of $4$ has vanished in the second term in equation (2) -> It was present in equation (1).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the answers to your both questions lie in one missing step:

$\bar{n_b}$ didn't come out of the partial time derivative.

\begin{equation}
m_p\frac{\partial(n_b u_b^j)}{\partial t} + 4Hm_pn_bu_b^j+\frac{1}{a}\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x^j}=F_{e\gamma}^j(\vec{x},t)\\
m_p\frac{\partial(\bar{n_b} (1+\delta_b) u_b^j)}{\partial t} + 4Hm_p\bar{n_b}(1+\delta_b)u_b^j+\frac{m_b \bar{n_b}(1+\delta_b)}{a}\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x^j}=F_{e\gamma}^j(\vec{x},t)\\
\end{equation}
So here we can ignore 2nd order terms
$
\delta_bu_b^j$ and $
\delta_b\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x^j}
$
\begin{align}
m_p\frac{\partial(\bar{n_b}u_b^j)}{\partial t} + 4Hm_p\bar{n_b}u_b^j+\frac{m_b \bar{n_b}}{a}\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x^j}=F_{e\gamma}^j(\vec{x},t)\\
m_p\frac{\partial \bar{n_b}}{\partial t}u_b^j+m_p\bar{n_b}\frac{\partial u_b^j}{\partial t}+ 4Hm_p\bar{n_b}u_b^j+\frac{m_b \bar{n_b}}{a}\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x^j}=F_{e\gamma}^j(\vec{x},t) \tag{1}\label{1}\\
\end{align}
And if you already derived the zeroth moment of Boltzmann Equation you know that

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial n_b}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{a}\frac{\partial (n_bu^j_b)}{\partial t} + 3[H+\dot{\Phi}]n_b = 0\\
\frac{\partial \big(\bar{n_b}(1+\delta_b)\big)}{\partial t} + \frac{1}{a}\frac{\partial \big(\bar{n_b}(1+\delta_b)u^j_b\big)}{\partial t} + 3[H+\dot{\Phi}]\bar{n_b}(1+\delta_b) = 0\\
\frac{\partial \bar{n_b}}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial \bar{n_b}}{\partial t}\delta_b + \frac{\partial \delta_b}{\partial t}\bar{n_b} + \frac{1}{a}\frac{\partial \big(\bar{n_b}u^j_b\big)}{\partial t} + 3H\bar{n_b}+3H\bar{n_b}\delta_b+3\bar{n_b}\dot{\Phi} = 0\\
\end{align}

And only 0th order terms:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \bar{n_b}}{\partial t} + 3H\bar{n_b} = 0 \tag{2}\label{2}\\
\end{align}

And if you implement \eqref{2} to \eqref{1} you will have

$$
m_p\bar{n_b}\frac{\partial u_b^j}{\partial t}+ Hm_p\bar{n_b}u_b^j+\frac{m_b \bar{n_b}}{a}\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial x^j}=F_{e\gamma}^j(\vec{x},t)\\
$$